# Order By Multiple Meta Fields

Tags: wp-query, mysql, meta-query

I have two custom fields:

- `meta_key1` is boolean (`0` or `1`).
- `meta_key2` is a date value - `20150623` for example.

Not all `meta_key2` fields have an explicit value. It looks like their being treated as an empty string `''`.

I'd like to find all posts that have a `meta_key2` (date) value that is greater than today or have a `meta_key1` value that is true.

This is the order I'd like them to display.

> 1. `key2.meta_value >= today ASC`
> 2. `key1.meta_value = TRUE ordered by date ASC` (those with dates given first).

Part of the issue is that fields with an empty date parameter appear to be treated as `0` and thus come first in `ASC` order. I've attempted to use `COALESCE` to account for this and have had some success but I'm hung up on one part. I can't get the posts that `key1.meta_value = FALSE` and `key2.meta_value is >= today` to display in `ASC` order.

Here's my query:

```
$meta_key1 = 'prog_ongoing';
$meta_key2 = 'prog_date_start';
$start_date = date('Ymd');

$postids = $wpdb->get_col( $wpdb->prepare( 
"
SELECT      DISTINCT key1.post_id
FROM        $wpdb->postmeta key1
INNER JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta key2
            ON key2.post_id = key1.post_id
            AND key2.meta_key = %s
WHERE       key1.meta_key = %s
            AND key1.meta_value is TRUE
            OR key2.meta_value >= %d
ORDER BY    COALESCE(NULLIF(key1.meta_value, 0), 0) DESC, COALESCE(NULLIF(key2.meta_value, ''), $start_date) ASC, key2.meta_value ASC 
",
$meta_key2,
$meta_key1,
$start_date
) );
```

I'm not sure my `COALESCE` statement on `key1.meta_value` is doing anything. Thanks for any insight on this.

Comment: As of WP 4.2, you can sort by multiple meta keys and values.  Whipping up an answer that shows this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One problem with the query is that the self-join with the ambiguous `WHERE` gives you a crossed dataset (which is masked by the `DISTINCT`), so it would be simpler to use `wp_post` as a base to attach the joins that precisely match the keys, eg

```
    SELECT      p.ID, key1.meta_value as prog_ongoing, key2.meta_value as prog_date_start
    FROM        $wpdb->posts p
    INNER JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta key1
                ON key1.post_id = p.ID
                AND key1.meta_key = %s
    INNER JOIN  $wpdb->postmeta key2
                ON key2.post_id = p.ID
                AND key2.meta_key = %s
```

which gives a linear dataset. Then you could add (or not) the `WHERE` clause to restrict the data:

```
    WHERE       key1.meta_value IS TRUE OR key2.meta_value >= %d
```

and for the `ORDER BY` use a `CASE` statement single field sort:

```
    ORDER BY    CASE
                    WHEN key2.meta_value >= %d THEN CONCAT('A', key2.meta_value)
                    WHEN key1.meta_value AND key2.meta_value THEN CONCAT('B', key2.meta_value)
                    WHEN key1.meta_value THEN 'C'
                    ELSE 'D'
                END ASC
```

or something similar, the above needing the `prepare` args to be:

```
    $meta_key1,
    $meta_key2,
    $start_date, $start_date
```

You could use the `posts_orderby` filter to do something similar using `WP_Query` (although it uses a method that produces crossed datasets, requiring it to have to use a `GROUP BY`, which can complicate things). For instance

```
$args = array(
    'posts_per_page' => -1,
    'post_type' => 'cpt_program',
    'meta_query' => array(
        'ongoing' => array(
            'key' => 'prog_ongoing',
        ),
        'start_date' => array(
            'key' => 'prog_date_start',
        )
    ),
);

add_filter( 'posts_orderby', $func = function ( $orderby, $query ) {
    $start_date = date('Ymd');
    global $wpdb;
    $orderby = $wpdb->prepare(
        "
        CASE
            WHEN mt1.meta_value >= %d THEN CONCAT('A', mt1.meta_value)
            WHEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value AND mt1.meta_value THEN CONCAT('B', mt1.meta_value)
            WHEN {$wpdb->postmeta}.meta_value THEN 'C'
            ELSE 'D'
        END ASC
        "
        , $start_date
    );
    return $orderby;
}, 10, 2 );
$query = new WP_Query( $args );
remove_filter( 'posts_orderby', $func, 10, 2 );
```

Comment: Excellent, that works :) Are you using the CONCAT and letters(A,B,C,D) as a way to sort alphabetically?

Comment: Good stuff - yes, though could use anything really, including numbers, but thought it slightly safer not to given the numeric data.

Comment: I'm trying to implement this by using WP_Query and the posts_orderby filter, but I'm not quite getting what I want. Any suggestions? Here's my code http://pastebin.com/VJ6s0WJa

Comment: I wouldn't do an `OR` I think, you want both meta values, also then the second postmeta (ie `prog_start_date`) is aliased as `mt1` by WP_Query... I'll update the answer with my attempt...

Comment: Thanks @bonger! This is very close, but I do need the `OR` though. Without it I get programs that are expired and not ongoing. It looks like simply adding the `OR` relation to the query jacks things up.

Answer (score 3):

First pass for a solution.  It uses the new meta sorting that was introduced in 4.2:

```
 <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            'ongoing' => array(
                'key'     => 'prog_ongoing',
                'value'   => 1
            ),
            'start_date' => array(
                array(
                    'key' => 'prog_date_start',
                    'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '>='
                )
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'start_date ongoing',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
    );

    $programs = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>
    <?php while($programs->have_posts()): $programs->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

I think I got the logic right, but let me know if otherwise

### EDIT

You can check out the new syntax to sort by multiple custom fields in Wordpress 4.2 in the following make

- [Query improvements in WP 4.2 orderby and meta query](https://make.wordpress.org/core/2015/03/30/query-improvements-in-wp-4-2-orderby-and-meta_query/)

Comment: Manny, I have edited your post to include the relevant link to the make article discussing this new syntax. To be honest, I did not know about it ;-). +1 for posting this as a solution

Comment: Thanks @Manny, I did not now about the new syntax. However, I'm still not getting the results I'd like. I've uploaded my results at http://pastebin.com/x8saFKsp if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `WP_Query()`? Lot simpler this way:

```
    <?php
    $args = array(
        'posts_per_page' => -1,
        'meta_query' => array(
            'relation' => 'OR',
            array(
                'key'     => 'prog_ongoing',
                'value'   => 1
            ),
            array(
                'relation' => 'AND',
                array(
                    'key' => 'prog_date_start',
                    'value'   => date('Ymd'),
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '<='
                ),
                array(
                   'key' => 'prog_date_start',
                    'value'   => 1,
                    'type'    => 'numeric',
                    'compare' => '>'
                )
            )
        ),
        'orderby' => 'meta_value_num date',
        'order'   => 'ASC',
        'meta_key' => 'prog_date_start'
    );

    $programs = new WP_Query($args);
    ?>
    <?php while($programs->have_posts()): $programs->the_post(); ?>
        <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
    <?php endwhile; ?>
```

Comment: Did you insert test data and run this code? I am not sure that it address the problem the OP is having, though `WP_Query` plus some filters would be the better way to go.

Comment: How does this solve the issue of sorting/ordering? I would use WP_Query, but you can't order by multiple custom fields without filtering. If I do filtering, I'm not sure how to account for the blank date fields - thus my question.

Comment: Yep, sorry, i understand your question now. You can pass an array into orderby in WP_Query to specify a fallback order if the default one wont work. I updated the code. Not sure if this would work for you, i tried it with a couple of posts but obviously i can't replicate the exact stuff you're trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @passatgt for looking into this. However, sorting by "date" in the order by array which is not a custom meta field. I want to sort by 'prog_ongoing' (those that are FALSE or not ongoing first) and then 'prog_date_start' within.